# Angular ng-view is not replacing the view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have below code as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/mainApp.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{Title}}</h1>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my angularjs file is as below

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']).run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.Title = "Alpha Bravo Charlie";
});

//routing
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    alert('hello');
     alert("hello2");
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        templateUrl:'views/view1.html',
        controller: 'CustController'

    });
});

mainApp.controller('CustController',function($scope){
    $scope.customers=[
            {name:'Dave Jones', city:'Dubai', number: '00001'},
            {name:'Nouman Ali', city:'Lahore', number: '00002'},
            {name:'Winz Cruz', city:'Dubai', number: '00003'},
            {name:'Roberto Mancini', city:'Per', number: '00004'},
            {name:'Dave Ands', city:'Abu Dhabi', number: '00005'},
        ];
});
```

It's change Title accordingly but I'm actually replacing view on run time, but as I load the index.html page there is nothing happening, and error is occurring on console as

> Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state
>   object with URL
>   'file:///D:/practice_code/nodejs/angular/views/index.html#/D:/' cannot
>   be created in a document with origin 'null'.

Comment: That error looks like it might be related to problems with the `file://` protocol. Can you replicate it when it's running from a locally installed web server?

Comment: You need to run webserver, don't use file protocol.

Comment: Yah after running webserver, 404. But when I use path like "views/view1.html" it's append an extra "views" and path become like "views/views/view1.html" but if I use "view1.html" direct then path become "http://localhost:11012/view1.html 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 1):

Please check or post your project folder structure here and where you are running your webserver. As per my observation, project path from "D:/practice_code/nodejs/angular/**views**/index.html" is seems to be inside views folder as index.html is under views folder.

Please check and run your webserver for correct directory